# Laravel : Validation not working when testing on live

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.5, laravel-validation

Create a user validate function with validation in API integration When i try to validate user with some validation and check it in `postman` it is working perfect in local machine but when i uploaded code on server and test, it is not working.

Controller function :

```
public function confirmUser(ForgotPasswordRequest $request)
{
    // ForgotPasswordRequest  for validate
    $user  = User::leftjoin('user_details','users.id', '=', 'user_details.user_id')
                ->where('user_details.phone', '=', $request->post('phone'))
                ->where('users.email', '=', $request->post('email'))
                ->first();
    if(!$user) {
        return response()->json([
                'message' => "The credentials you provided cannot be determined to be authentic.!!",
                'status_code' => 404,
        ]);
    }
    $token = JWTAuth::fromUser($user);
    return response()->json([
        'message'       => "Your account is eligible for change password.!!",
        'token'         => $token,
        'status_code'   => 200
    ]);
}
```

My `forgotPasswordRequest.php` code :

```
<?php

namespace App\Api\V1\Requests;

use Config;
use Dingo\Api\Http\FormRequest;

class ForgotPasswordRequest extends FormRequest
{
    public function rules()
    {
        return Config::get('boilerplate.forgot_password.validation_rules');
    }

    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

And in `config` folder `boilerplate.php` file contain `forgot_password` rules :

```
  'forgot_password' => [

        'validation_rules' => [
        'email' => 'required|email',
        'phone' => 'required|min:11|numeric'
    ]
],
```

When `email` and `phone` null it returns only `email` validation not `phone`:

```
{
"error": {
    "message": "422 Unprocessable Entity",
    "errors": {
        "email": [
            "The email field is required."
        ]
    },
    "status_code": 422
}
}
```

What i am doing wrong ? It is related to cookies ?

Comment: What's the error? "It works locally, but not in production" is generally due to other changes not being pushed, or that the environments are completely different.

Comment: @Loek added `validation` response.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing going wrong here.

Laravel checks whether the `email` field is properly filled in. It isn't, Laravel breaks out of the validation method and returns the exception.

If you fill in the `email` field, but leave the `phone` field blank, then the validation response will be about the `phone` field.

Comment: Undestand that but when `email` field is not null and `phone` is NULL then it directly check `if(!$user)` and return `The credentials you provided cannot be determined to be authentic.!!`

Comment: Okay, that's a different question entirely. Maybe the config file is cached in your live situation? Try running `php artisan config:clear` and `php artisan config:cache` (remember to do this every time you push to production, but only if you want the file cached!)